# Application of Fitting's Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, nilpotence

> Let $R$ be a ring. Let $M$ be an indecomposable $R$-module with length $n$.
> Let $f\in\operatorname{End}(M)\setminus\operatorname{Aut}(M)$.
>
> Show that $f^n=0$

What I have so far:

We can apply Fitting's Lemma, it tells us directly that $f$ is nilpotent.

If $f$ is nilpotent $\exists m$ s.t. $f^m=0$ and $\{f, f^2,...,f^{m-1}\}$ are all nonzero. Now we consider the chain $0 \subseteq ker f \subseteq....\subseteq kerf^{m-1}\subsetneq kerf^m =M$ where $kerf^{m-1}\subsetneq kerf^m$ holds because $f^{m-1}$ is assumed to be nonzero.

Suppose at some point we have $kerf^{i} = ker f^{i+1}$ for some $1 \leq i \leq m-1$. Then by some simple calculations we get that $ker f^{i}=kerf^{r}$ $\forall i \leq r \leq m$ and in particular $M=kerf^m=kerf^{i}$ which yields $f^{i}=0$. This contradicts our assumption that $\{f, f^2,...,f^{m-1}\}$ are all nonzero.

Hence we get a proper sequence $0 \subseteq ker f \subsetneq kerf^2 \subsetneq...\subsetneq kerf^m=M$. Since $M$ has length $n$ we can conclude $m \leq n$ and therefore $f^n=0$.

Is this correct?

Comment: This is less of an application of the lemma and more a refinement of it.  Re-examining the proof of the original lemma, it is clear why the length of the module is going to limit the index of nilpotency.

Comment: @rschwieb I have seen the proof. But the proof says that the ascending chain of $ker f^i \subset ker f^{i+1}$ cannot go on forever but I need that $ker f^i \subsetneq ker f^{i+1}$

Comment: But yeah, that's an *understatement*.  Not only can it not go on forever, $i$ most certainly can't exceed $n$.  You can't fit that many proper containments in a tower of submodules of a length $n$ module.  Everything that's nilpotent would reach zero in at most $n$ steps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea, perhaps details are missing:
Since $f$ is nilpotent, you have that $f^m=0$ for some $m$. Suppose $\{1,f,\dots,f^{m-1}\}$ are all nonzero. Then $Ker f^{i+1}\supsetneq Ker f^i$ and these are submodules. So you get an increasing sequence of proper submodules of $M$. Since the length of $M$ is $n$, it follows that $m\leq n$, and so $f^n=0$.

Comment: thank you:) but how do you know that $Ker f^{i} \subsetneq Ker f^{i+1}$?I am sorry, I haven't really studied abstract algebra a lot :/

Comment: The containment $Ker f^i\subseteq Ker f^{i+1}$ is clear, because if $f^i(v)=0$ then $f^{i+1}(v)=f(0)=0$. You just need to show the containment is strict so that the length of the chain is exactly $m$. This is where the details are missing but I think it could be shown.

Comment: yes exactly, the strictness is what I am struggling with, but I will think some more about it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: are you Sure it can be shown with moderate algebra knowledge? Because I really am no algebra expert

Comment: @mathStudent I had another idea, use instead the chain given by $Im f^i$. Now the chain starts at $Im f^m=\{0\}$ and goes up to $Im f \subsetneq M$. If there is a point where $Im f^{i+1} = Im f^{i}$, then $f^{r}= f^{i}$ for all $r\geq i$, in particular $f^m=f^i=0$. But then if you take $m$ minimal then $i=m$. Then you have your result. I still think that for the kernels some similar argument should be possible.

Comment: how does $f^r=f^{i}, i \leq r$ follow from $Im f^{i+1} = Im f^{i}$?

Comment: @mathStudent yeah sorry I meant $Im f^r= Im f^i$, and $Im f^m=Im f^i=0$ so $i=m$. It is just like the argument you completed with the kernel.